# Manipulating a div using vue js methods

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm taking an online course which corrects code using a bot.

The instructions are to make the code...

```
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <input v-model="userName">
    <input type="submit" value="Spela">
  </form>
  <div>{{ message }}</div>
</div>
```

... change the value in the inner div-element to "Hey", followed by what's in the text field, followed by an "!" when you press Enter. To do this initialize `username` , `message` and `null`

This is my JS code so far, but I'm stuck.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onClick: function () {

    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Maybe start with the [Introduction](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

Answer (score 0):

add **data** section with *username* and *message*:

```
data: {
  return {
    username: null,
    message: null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application should look like this:

```js
// initial data goes in data
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
    message: null,
    userName: null
  },
  methods: {
    // change onClick to onSubmit (the function name..)
    // a method here is the function passed from an event
    onSubmit: function (e) {
      this.message = this.userName + '!'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <input v-model="userName">
    <input type="submit" value="Spela">
  </form>
  <div>{{ message }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think I understand. The bot gave me an output of `✓ exists
    ✓ is valid JavaScript
    ✓ initializes message to null
    ✓ initializes userName to null
    1) has an onSubmit method which renders the correct message for the value “Alice”
    2) has an onSubmit method which renders the correct message for some value`

Comment: @JSCOTT so all true, what's left? and what is the website's name